# What I am trying to do is, to eliminate all rows which are having modified date less than the maximum date for each entry in CI_NAME column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DELETE FROM MOBILE_CELONIS_SITES 
WHERE CI_NAME IN (SELECT CI_NAME 
                  FROM MOBILE_CELONIS_SITES 
                  GROUP BY CI_NAME 
                  HAVING COUNT(CI_NAME) > 1) 
HAVING MODIFIED_DATE != (SELECT MAX(MODIFIED_DATE) 
                         FROM MOBILE_CELONIS_SITES 
                         GROUP BY CI_NAME);
```

I get an error:

> Execution error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'HAVING'.

What I am trying to do is, to eliminate all rows which are having modified date less than the maximum date for each entry in `CI_NAME` column

Comment: At most one `having` clause per `select`.

Comment: yaa I am using one select but other one is in different query

Comment: And no `HAVING` in `DELETE`.

Comment: Just switch the second `HAVING` to `AND`

Answer (score 1):

Use `exists` as follows:

```
DELETE FROM MOBILE_CELONIS_SITES t
WHERE exists 
      (Select 1 from MOBILE_CELONIS_SITES tt
        Where t.CI_NAME = tt.CI_NAME
          And tt.MODIFIED_DATE > t.MODIFIED_DATE)
```

Comment: I am getting this error while executing this query Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Comment: Have you copied the exact query? I can not see any issue with the query.